# How to create color selector in a drop-down style using style tag?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, color-picker

As shown in this link..  [I want to make a color list of this type](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gica3r4tr3b3nmu/IMG_20170630_175107.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: @Dinesh I have used this already.. but i cannot achievethe color dot before the list items.

Comment: i updated my answer check now

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any code. Here i'm giving you an idea. from this you can create.

```css
body{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="form-control">

<option value="blue" style="color:blue">&#9679;  blue</option>
<option value="red" style="color:red">&#9679; red</option>
<option value="green" style="color:green">&#9679; green</option>
<option value="black" style="color:black">&#9679; black</option>
<option value="yellow" style="color:yellow">&#9679; yellow</option>



</select>
```